# Нужно передать переменную функции из одного класса в переменную функции другого класса

Tags: python, tkinter, наследование

Сейчас делаю 2D-проект "Солнечная система".

Как и следует из названия, нужно сделать солнечную систему 2D, в движении. С помощью библиотеки tkinter. В центре должно находиться Солнце, вокруг Солнца должно крутиться 9 планет, **а вокруг планет должны крутиться спутники**, вот с этим и возникли проблемы. Если привязку планет к неподвижному центру (Солнцу) сделать получилось легко, то привязать спутники к подвижным планетам (с постоянно меняющимся центром), оказалось гораздо сложнее.

Как из класса `Mercury`, функции `update` можно передать центр планеты Меркурий, в класс `Satellite_Of_Mercury`, собственно, чтобы наш спутник понимал, где центр планеты. Также центр планеты всё время обновляется и соответственно нужно каждый раз обновлять и центр у спутника!

Пробовал делать с помощью метода `super()`, но, как выяснилось, он не может получить доступ к атрибутам. Метод наследования тоже не сильно помог. Пробовал задавать ему необходимое поле через сеттер или конструировать класс на основе необходимого поля, но ввиду нехватки опыта не смог с этим разобраться :(

Конечная цель: планета крутится вокруг Солнца, спутник - вокруг планеты. Данный код рабочий, в нём есть Солнце, планета, крутящаяся вокруг Солнца, и спутник (но он без привязки к центру планеты и пока что просто крутиться по заданным координатам, собственно то, что и не получилось).

````py
from tkinter import *
from random import *
from math import *
import time

# Создаем окно программы
root = Tk()
# Создаем область для рисования
c = Canvas(root, width=600, height=600, bg="white")
c.pack()

class Mercury:
    def __init__(self, canvas, center, dist):
        self.angle = 0      # текущий угол
        self.radius = 10    # радиус кружка
        self.canvas = canvas    # ссылка на рисовалку для удобства
        self.center = center    # центр окружности
        self.dist = dist    # расстояние до центра
        self.x, self.y = self.p2c() # преобразуем угол в координаты. 
        # Рисуем начальное положение
        self.shape = canvas.create_oval(self.x - self.radius, self.y - self.radius, self.x + self.radius, self.y + self.radius, fill='red')
        # Запускаем анимацию
        self.update()
        print(self.x, self.y)
    def update(self):
        # Вычисляем новые координаты
        new = self.p2c()
        # Двигаем кружок на дельту
        self.canvas.move(self.shape, new[0]-self.x, new[1]-self.y)
        # Сохраняем новые кординаты как текущие
        (self.x, self.y) = new
        # Через 15мс (примерно соответствует 60 кадрам в сек) повторяем
        self.canvas.after(90, self.update)
        # Увеличиваем угол
        self.angle -= 0.03

    # Это по сути преобразование от полярных к декартовым.
    def p2c(self):
        return cos(self.angle) * self.dist + self.center[0], sin(self.angle) * self.dist + self.center[1]
    
class Satellite_Of_Mercury:
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.angle = 0  # текущий угол
        self.radius = 4  # радиус кружка
        self.canvas = canvas    # ссылка на рисовалку для удобства
        self.center = (500, 300)  # центр окружности
        self.dist = 20  # расстояние до центра
        self.x, self.y = self.p2c() # преобразуем угол в координаты. 
        # Рисуем начальное положение
        self.shape = canvas.create_oval(self.x - self.radius, self.y - self.radius, self.x + self.radius, self.y + self.radius, fill='red')
        # Запускаем анимацию
        self.update()
                
    def update(self):
        # Вычисляем новые координаты
        new = self.p2c()
        # Двигаем кружок на дельту
        self.canvas.move(self.shape, new[0]-self.x, new[1]-self.y)
        # Сохраняем новые кординаты как текущие
        (self.x, self.y) = new
        # Через 15мс (примерно соответствует 60 кадрам в сек) повторяем
        self.canvas.after(90, self.update)
        # Увеличиваем угол
        self.angle -= 0.5

    # Это по сути преобразование от полярных к декартовым.
    def p2c(self):
        return cos(self.angle) * self.dist + self.center[0], sin(self.angle) * self.dist + self.center[1]
    
# Статичные элементы рисовать легко
c.create_oval(100, 100, 500, 500)   
 
dot9 = Mercury(c, (300, 300), 200)
Sun = Mercury(c, (300, 300), 0)

dot09 = Satellite_Of_Mercury(c)

# Запускаем главный цикл
root.mainloop() ```
````

Comment: сделай в классе ``Mercury`` поле ``центр_планеты``. Ну или что ты там используешь. Главное, чтобы имя отличалось от имени в классе-наследнике. Тогда сможешь обращаться к нему из наследника. А сейчас у тебя все поля родительского класса перекрываются наследником, потому и значения не можешь получить.

Answer (score 1):

> Как из класса Mercury, функции update можно передать центр планеты Меркурий, в класс Satellite_Of_Mercury, собственно, чтобы наш спутник понимал, где центр планеты.

Для этого нужно, чтоб в классе Mercury была ссылка на объект `Satellite_Of_Mercury`, которую Mercury может использовать, когда координаты меняются и уведомлять об этом спутник. Простой способ это при создании спутника передавать ему планету, чтоб спутник зарегистрировал себя в списке спутников планеты.

Дальше в коде я показал только измененные части, остальное остается как и было раньше:

```
class Mercury:
    def __init__(self, canvas, center, dist):
        ... все как и раньше
        # Рисуем начальное положение
        self.shape = canvas.create_oval(...)
        # Запускаем анимацию
        self.children = []
        self.update()
        print(self.x, self.y)

    def add_child(self, child):
        self.children.append(child)

    def update(self):
        ... все как и раньше
        (self.x, self.y) = new
        for child in self.children:
            child.parent_moved(self.x, self.y)
        # Через 15мс (примерно соответствует 60 кадрам в сек) повторяем
        self.canvas.after(90, self.update)
        # Увеличиваем угол
        self.angle -= 0.03

    
class Satellite_Of_Mercury:
    def __init__(self, canvas, parent):
        ... все как и раньше
        self.update()
        parent.add_child(self)

    def parent_moved(self, x, y):
        self.center = (x, y)
                
    def update(self):
        ... все как и раньше
 
dot9 = Mercury(c, (300, 300), 200)
Sun = Mercury(c, (300, 300), 0)

dot09 = Satellite_Of_Mercury(c, parent=dot9)
```

Comment: Добрый день. Сделал всё, как вы сказали, но мне выдаёт программа: name 'children' is not defined. Может я что-то не так ввожу или в Вашей инструкции где-то неточность? Можете дать полный код, заранее спасибо!